# Responsive Web Desgin Without Grid System

Tags: web, responsive-design, media-queries, frontend

I am doing a project on Responsive Web Design (RWD).
Framework like Bootstrap or Foundation or 960 is using grids system as base layout.
I am specifically looking for solution (framework) beside the ones with grids system, but still achieving the responsive components.

And if there is a pro and con comparing that to grids system.

If you known of any please shoot me a link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason why grid systems are used so widely. The grid is, in my opinion, the easiest way to define how your content is laid in the page, as you don't have to deal with CSS properties and values like margin, padding, floats etc. I would suggest that you stick to a framework with a grid system if there is no good reason to do otherwise.

That being said, you can always experiment with other frameworks, like [Gridless](http://thatcoolguy.github.io/gridless-boilerplate/) (keep in mind that it hasn't been updated for quite some time).

Comment: The reason that I was asking about other system because my project is trying to compare different solutions to RWD. I myself use grid a lot, but for the theme of the project is trying to come up with comparison of alternate method. Thanks for the Gridless link.